# JAVA error: constructor LoginModel in class LoginModel cannot be applied to given types;

Tags: java, netbeans

Olá! Estou aprendendo a programar java no NetBeans mas está dando o seguinte erro ao executar os códigos abaixo:

**Task :app:compileJava FAILED
C:\Users\crist\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProjetoLanchonete\app\src\main\java\ProjetoLanchonete\formCadastroUsu.java:262: error: constructor LoginModel in class LoginModel cannot be applied to given types;
LoginModel CadUsuario = new LoginModel();
^
required: int,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String
found:    no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileJava'.
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.

Meus códigos:

package Modelo;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class LoginModel {

```
//Declarando as variáveis

private int tb_UsuarioID;
private String tb_UsuarioNome;
private String tb_UsuarioEndereco;
private String tb_UsuarioNumero;
private String tb_UsuarioComplemento;
private String tb_UsuarioCidade;
private String tb_UsuarioEstado;
private String tb_UsuarioBairro;
private String tb_UsuarioCEP;
private String tb_UsuarioOBS;
private String tb_UsuarioCelular;

public LoginModel(int tb_UsuarioID, String tb_UsuarioNome, String tb_UsuarioEndereco, String tb_UsuarioNumero, String tb_UsuarioComplemento, String tb_UsuarioCidade, String tb_UsuarioEstado, String tb_UsuarioBairro, String tb_UsuarioCEP, String tb_UsuarioOBS, String tb_UsuarioCelular) { 
    this.tb_UsuarioID = tb_UsuarioID;
    this.tb_UsuarioNome = tb_UsuarioNome;
    this.tb_UsuarioEndereco = tb_UsuarioEndereco;
    this.tb_UsuarioNumero = tb_UsuarioNumero;
    this.tb_UsuarioComplemento = tb_UsuarioComplemento;
    this.tb_UsuarioCidade = tb_UsuarioCidade;
    this.tb_UsuarioEstado = tb_UsuarioEstado;
    this.tb_UsuarioBairro = tb_UsuarioBairro;
    this.tb_UsuarioCEP = tb_UsuarioCEP;
    this.tb_UsuarioOBS = tb_UsuarioOBS;
    this.tb_UsuarioCelular = tb_UsuarioCelular;
}

public int getTb_UsuarioID() {
    return tb_UsuarioID;
}

public String getTb_UsuarioNome() {
    return tb_UsuarioNome;
}

public String getTb_UsuarioEndereco() {
    return tb_UsuarioEndereco;
}

public String getTb_UsuarioNumero() {
    return tb_UsuarioNumero;
}

public String getTb_UsuarioComplemento() {
    return tb_UsuarioComplemento;
}

public String getTb_UsuarioCidade() {
    return tb_UsuarioCidade;
}

public String getTb_UsuarioEstado() {
    return tb_UsuarioEstado;
}

public String getTb_UsuarioBairro() {
    return tb_UsuarioBairro;
}

public String getTb_UsuarioCEP() {
    return tb_UsuarioCEP;
}

public String getTb_UsuarioOBS() {
    return tb_UsuarioOBS;
}

public String getTb_UsuarioCelular() {
    return tb_UsuarioCelular;
}

public void setTb_UsuarioID(int tb_UsuarioID) {
    this.tb_UsuarioID = tb_UsuarioID;
}

public void setTb_UsuarioNome(String tb_UsuarioNome) {
    this.tb_UsuarioNome = tb_UsuarioNome;
}

public void setTb_UsuarioEndereco(String tb_UsuarioEndereco) {
    this.tb_UsuarioEndereco = tb_UsuarioEndereco;
}

public void setTb_UsuarioNumero(String tb_UsuarioNumero) {
    this.tb_UsuarioNumero = tb_UsuarioNumero;
}

public void setTb_UsuarioComplemento(String tb_UsuarioComplemento) {
    this.tb_UsuarioComplemento = tb_UsuarioComplemento;
}

public void setTb_UsuarioCidade(String tb_UsuarioCidade) {
    this.tb_UsuarioCidade = tb_UsuarioCidade;
}

public void setTb_UsuarioEstado(String tb_UsuarioEstado) {
    this.tb_UsuarioEstado = tb_UsuarioEstado;
}

public void setTb_UsuarioBairro(String tb_UsuarioBairro) {
    this.tb_UsuarioBairro = tb_UsuarioBairro;
}

public void setTb_UsuarioCEP(String tb_UsuarioCEP) {
    this.tb_UsuarioCEP = tb_UsuarioCEP;
}

public void setTb_UsuarioOBS(String tb_UsuarioOBS) {
    this.tb_UsuarioOBS = tb_UsuarioOBS;
}

public void setTb_UsuarioCelular(String tb_UsuarioCelular) {
    this.tb_UsuarioCelular = tb_UsuarioCelular;
}
```

---

package ProjetoLanchonete;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import Controlador.classLoginDAO;
import Modelo.LoginModel;
import utilidades.ConexaoDB;

public class formCadastroUsu extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
 classLoginDAO classLoginDAO;

public formCadastroUsu() {
    initComponents();
}

private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      

    try {

      LoginModel CadUsuario = new LoginModel();
     
        CadUsuario.setTb_UsuarioNome(TextFieldNome.getText());
        CadUsuario.setTb_UsuarioEndereco(TextFieldEndereco.getText());
        CadUsuario.setTb_UsuarioNumero(TextFieldNumero.getText());
        CadUsuario.setTb_UsuarioComplemento(TextFieldComplemento.getText());   
        CadUsuario.setTb_UsuarioCidade(TextFieldCidade.getText());
        CadUsuario.setTb_UsuarioEstado(TextFieldEstado.getText());          
        CadUsuario.setTb_UsuarioBairro(TextFieldBairro.getText());
        CadUsuario.setTb_UsuarioCEP(TextFieldCEP.getText());    
        CadUsuario.setTb_UsuarioOBS(TextAreaOBS.getText());
        CadUsuario.setTb_UsuarioCelular(TextFieldCelular.getText());    
        
        classLoginDAO.salvarUsuario(CadUsuario);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Projeto salva com sucesso");
        dispose();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, e);
    }
    
   
}
```

---

package Controlador;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import Modelo.LoginModel;
import java.sql.Connection;
import utilidades.ConexaoDB;
public class classLoginDAO {

```
    public void salvarUsuario(LoginModel CadUsuario) {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO projects(tb_UsuarioNome,"
            + "tb_UsuarioEndereco)"
            + "tb_UsuarioNumero,"
            + "tb_UsuarioComplemento, "
            + "tb_UsuarioCidade, "
            + "tb_UsuarioEstado, "
            + "tb_UsuarioBairro,"
            + "tb_UsuarioCEP, "
            + "tb_UsuarioOBS,"
            + "getTb_UsuarioCelular,"
            
            + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;

    try {
     
        conn = ConexaoDB.getConnection();
    
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        stmt.setString(1, CadUsuario.getTb_UsuarioNome());
        stmt.setString(2, CadUsuario.getTb_UsuarioEndereco());
        stmt.setString(3, CadUsuario.getTb_UsuarioNumero());
        stmt.setString(4, CadUsuario.getTb_UsuarioComplemento());
        stmt.setString(5, CadUsuario.getTb_UsuarioCidade());
        stmt.setString(6, CadUsuario.getTb_UsuarioEstado());          
        stmt.setString(7, CadUsuario.getTb_UsuarioBairro());
        stmt.setString(8, CadUsuario.getTb_UsuarioCEP());  
      stmt.setString(9, CadUsuario.getTb_UsuarioOBS());
     stmt.setString(10, CadUsuario.getTb_UsuarioCelular());
   
                 stmt.execute();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Erro ao salvar o projeto", ex);
    } finally {
                try {
            if (stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Erro ao fechar a conexão", ex);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Pois não consigo entender o erro.

Answer (score 0):

Sua classe LoginModel tem apenas este construtor:

```
public LoginModel(int tb_UsuarioID, String tb_UsuarioNome, String tb_UsuarioEndereco, String tb_UsuarioNumero, String tb_UsuarioComplemento, String tb_UsuarioCidade, String tb_UsuarioEstado, String tb_UsuarioBairro, String tb_UsuarioCEP, String tb_UsuarioOBS, String tb_UsuarioCelular) {
```

Mas você está tentando criar uma instância dela chamando:

```
LoginModel CadUsuario = new LoginModel();
```

Você tem duas opções a seguir:

1. criar um construtor em LoginModel sem parâmetros
2. criar a instância de LoginModel com o construtor existente, passando todos os parâmetros (tb_UsuarioID, tb_UsuarioNome, ...)

Pela sequência do seu código parece que a opção 1 é a correta.